# How do I get the Control that is under the cursor in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, focus, mouse-cursor, setfocus

I need the opposite information that the question ["How to get cursor position on a control?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647817/delphi-how-to-get-cursor-position-on-a-control) asks.

Given the current cursor position, how can I find the form (in my application) and the control that the cursor is currently over? I need the handle to it so that I can use `Windows.SetFocus(Handle)`.

For reference, I'm using Delphi 2009.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `FindVCLWindow` will meet your needs. Once you have the windowed control under the cursor you can walk the parent chain to find the form on which the window lives.

Comment: Is it as easy as that? I looked up FindVCLWindow on SO and found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078472/using-findvclwindow-to-call-winhelp32-winxp-pro-sp3-32bit-in-delphi and in that they are also adjusting the CursorPosition and one of the comments in the answer mentioned a problem with FindVCLWindow.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `FindVCLWindow`?

Comment: It is as simple. Gamecat provided an alternative, but the OP came back with his own answer explaining he had done something wrong in his event handlers. His own answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078472/using-findvclwindow-to-call-winhelp32-winxp-pro-sp3-32bit-in-delphi/1078808#1078808 ) indeed simply uses FindVCLWindow.

Comment: You can use `GetParentForm` in forms.pas that walks the parent chain for you.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced some problems with suggested solutions (Delphi XE6/Windows 8.1/x64):

- FindVCLWindow doesn't search disabled controls (Enabled=False).
- TWinControl.ControlAtPos doesn't search controls if they are disabled
  indirectly (for example if Button.Enabled=True, but Button.Parent.Enabled=False).

In my case it was a problem, because i need to find any visible control under the mouse cursor, so i have to use my own implementation of function `FindControlAtPos`:

```
function FindSubcontrolAtPos(AControl: TControl; AScreenPos, AClientPos: TPoint): TControl;
var
  i: Integer;
  C: TControl;
begin
  Result := nil;
  C := AControl;
  if (C=nil) or not C.Visible or not TRect.Create(C.Left, C.Top, C.Left+C.Width, C.Top+C.Height).Contains(AClientPos) then
    Exit;
  Result := AControl;
  if AControl is TWinControl then
    for i := 0 to TWinControl(AControl).ControlCount-1 do
    begin
      C := FindSubcontrolAtPos(TWinControl(AControl).Controls[i], AScreenPos, AControl.ScreenToClient(AScreenPos));
      if C<>nil then
        Result := C;
    end;
end;

function FindControlAtPos(AScreenPos: TPoint): TControl;
var
  i: Integer;
  f,m: TForm;
  p: TPoint;
  r: TRect;
begin
  Result := nil;
  for i := Screen.FormCount-1 downto 0 do
    begin
      f := Screen.Forms[i];
      if f.Visible and (f.Parent=nil) and (f.FormStyle<>fsMDIChild) and 
        TRect.Create(f.Left, f.Top, f.Left+f.Width, f.Top+f.Height).Contains(AScreenPos) 
      then
        Result := f; 
    end;
  Result := FindSubcontrolAtPos(Result, AScreenPos, AScreenPos);
  if (Result is TForm) and (TForm(Result).ClientHandle<>0) then
  begin
    WinAPI.Windows.GetWindowRect(TForm(Result).ClientHandle, r);
    p := TPoint.Create(AScreenPos.X-r.Left, AScreenPos.Y-r.Top);
    m := nil;
    for i := TForm(Result).MDIChildCount-1 downto 0 do
    begin
      f := TForm(Result).MDIChildren[i];
      if TRect.Create(f.Left, f.Top, f.Left+f.Width, f.Top+f.Height).Contains(p) then
        m := f; 
    end;
    if m<>nil then
      Result := FindSubcontrolAtPos(m, AScreenPos, p);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for adding your answer even this late. I never got it working perfectly myself, and I'm going to try this and see if it's better.

Comment: @lkessler I updated the code, now it is compatible with MDI-forms too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the control inside a form that is at a certain x,y coordinate

Use

```
function TWinControl.ControlAtPos(const Pos: TPoint; AllowDisabled: Boolean;
        AllowWinControls: Boolean = False; AllLevels: Boolean = False): TControl;
```

Given the fact that you seem only interested in forms inside your application, you can just query all forms.

Once you get a non-nil result, you can query the control for its Handle, with code like the following

**Pseudo code**

```
function HandleOfControlAtCursor: THandle;
const
  AllowDisabled = true;
  AllowWinControls = true;
  AllLevels = true;
var
  CursorPos: TPoint
  FormPos: TPoint;
  TestForm: TForm;
  ControlAtCursor: TControl;
begin
  Result:= THandle(0);
  GetCursorPos(CursorPos);
  for each form in my application do begin
    TestForm:= Form_to_test;
    FormPos:= TestForm.ScreenToClient(CursorPos);
    ControlAtCursor:= TestForm.ControlAtPos(FormPos,  AllowDisabled,
                                            AllowWinControls, AllLevels);
    if Assigned(ControlAtCursor) then break;
  end; {for each}
  //Break re-enters here
  if Assigned(ControlAtCursor) then begin
    while not(ControlAtCursor is TWinControl) do 
      ControlAtCursor:= ControlAtCursor.Parent;
    Result:= ControlAtCursor.Handle;
  end; {if}
end;
```

This also allows you to exclude certain forms from consideration should you so desire. If you're looking for simplicity I'd go with David and use `FindVCLWindow`.

P.S. Personally I'd use a `goto` rather than a break, because with a goto it's instantly clear where the break re-enters, but in this case it's not a big issue because there are no statements in between the break and the re-entry point.

Comment: I've never done that (querying all forms) before. My program may have a half dozen open at once. How do I go about doing that, I mean iterating through all of them rather than hardcoding them?

Comment: @David: So are you supporting Johan's answer, or your own FindVCLWindow answer?

Comment: I was merely answering your question about iterating over forms. If you don't have a form then I think FindVclWindow may be cleaner. It's hard to say for sure. Only you can know.